# Copper water water line is out of round slightly

Tags: copper

Copper pipe water line is out of round....can I still use a compression fitting valve and just add some teflon tape at the compression nut to ring seat fit.  it is slightly oval.  I noticed a slight wetness just behind compression fitting.  I think I can reset it with a little Teflon placed over the ring setting where the nut stresses down on it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that teflon tape will help with an out of round tube in a compression fitting. My first thought would be to try to restore the tube to roundness by proper use of Vise-Grips with a rag to prevent scoring of the sealing ring. There is a die clamp device designed for gripping tubing to make a flare in the end. This die might be used to restore the tubing to roundness. You might have to remove the ring seal and put on a new one after truing the end of the tubing.

But be prepared to cut off the out of round end and join a fresh piece of good tubing.

Comment: I might try to round the pipe like Jim says but if already tightened. I would tighten it further and that should pinch the ferrul on the tubing and seal, using Teflon on a compression fitting is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree with @Ed beal on this, attempt to further tighten and it might seal up. What have you got to lose, it already leaks and is out-of-round. IMO people often do not tighten compression fittings enough.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - Guilty. Mine always leak the first time.